# Copying some data of a file and pasting it to another file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a file, where I want to copy some data of the file and paste it to another file, for example suppose a file contains the following data:

```
AlphaforBravo007 102000000010170000000001 SusanaForCharlie 1000 end
```

From the above text I want to copy `102000000010170000000001` and `1000` respectively and paste it to a new file, each on new row.

I would really appreciate any hint.

Comment: I love python but...`awk '{print $2 "\n" $4}' old.txt >new.txt` I made this a comment not an answer because I didn't want to get -1 battered back into the stone age for not being what you asked for (python) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1,open('file2.txt','w') as f2:
 for line in f1: 
   x=line.split()   #now x is ['AlphaforBravo007', '102000000010170000000001', 'SusanaForCharlie', '1000', 'end']
   f2.write('\n'.join((x[1],x[3]))+'\n')
```

now `file2.txt` contains:

```
102000000010170000000001
1000
```

Comment: after splitting the line I am only writing `x[1]` and `x[3]` to the file, which are the desired positions.

Comment: @Shaheryar you should accept the solution if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in file1:
    a, b, c, d, e = line.split()
    file2.write(' '.join((b, d)) + '\n')
```

Hints:

- learn how to read in a file (preferably line by line)
- basic text handling - look up the various string methods (`split`)
- learn how to write out to a file
- practice describing your problem - once well described, you will find it half solved...

Comment: @Daren ahan Thanks, I know how to do it java, I am just new to Python but tht hint would help, I believe. Bravo !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the second and fourth column only from a whitespace-separated text file, you can use

```py
columns = operator.itemgetter(1, 3)
with open("input.txt") as input, open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in input:
        output.write(" ".join(columns(line.split())) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply copy the numbers and avoid the text from a file to another you could use something like this:

```
import re
with open('number.txt') as f1,open('number2.txt','w') as f2:
    for line in f1: 
        lst=line.split()
        for parts in lst:
            if not re.search('[A-Za-z]', parts): # Look for any alphabetical character in parts
                if lst[1] == parts:
                    f2.write(parts)
                else:
                    f2.write('\n' + parts)
```

this gives:

```
102000000010170000000001
1000
```